# How do I post the property content with umbraco?

Tags: metadata, umbraco

Our website has been made so that the meta title only changes very little, and the meta description doesn't change at all on the different pages.

I'm very much a noob with Umbraco, so I don't know how to handle this problem:

This is the [current template code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hlod.png):

@Model.Content.Name - Højskolen på Kalø

In each page, there is a tab called [Meta Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VYp8.png)
, where I can add Meta Title, but the content is not displayed anywhere.

How can I pull that content and display in in the code above?

Do I need some info from the [document type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjUvi.png)?

Comment: Have a look at how to render content (using properties) here: https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Design/Rendering-Content/

Comment: Right, so I've got some kind of solution:
`@(Model.Content.HasValue("metaTitle") ? Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("metaTitle") : Model.Content.Name)`
, but now I'm stuck with special characters like **ÆØÅ** not being displayed properly... 
I've set the     `<meta charset="UTF-8">` but I still get &#198;&#216;&#197;

Comment: Hm. Try wrapping the whole thing in a @Html.Raw(...) thing? Sounds strange though.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... but when I change the code to this: `@(Model.Content.HasValue("metaTitle") ? Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("metaTitle") : Model.Content.Name) - slutning ÆØÅ`

I get this: _meta titlen er her &#198;&#216;&#197; - slutning ÆØÅ_

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to decode the special characters:

```
@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Content.HasValue("metaTitle") ? Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("metaTitle") : Model.Content.Name) - slutning ÆØÅ
```

You may or may not have to wrap the above with Html.Raw, but that should work.